# Traceroutes to every site includes nameintelligence.com

Tags: networking

I used domaintools.com to do a traceroute on a bunch of sites, and noticed that every single one leads to this "nameintelligence.com" site that I have never heard of.

Absolutely every site, including this one, google, my own site, yahoo, microsoft.com, stackoverflow, EVERYTHING, has nameintelligence.com in the first position.

What is that site, and what do they do? They're a PR 4 apparently, yet I have never heard of them.

I think this would be the right place to ask, I am sorry if I am wrong.

Here is the traceroute for google: http://dns-tools.domaintools.com/ip-tools/?method=traceroute&query=74.125.53.99

Comment: Apparently that is the company who created domaintools.com, could it be that they are including their own request in the listing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're reading the traceroute backwards. Every traceroute has a FIRST HOP of nameitellegence.com which is just the next-hop router from domaintools.com. in your example, the last hope router is: pw-in-f99.1e100.net

So it's going Domain Tools -> nameinstellegence router -> ... routers ... -> Last hop router.

Comment: That'd do it. Read my comment on the question, I thought I must have been misreading it lol...Thank you!